# Moq mocking a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

I'm new to Moq and mocking.

I have a class `Car` and I want to Mock this class:

```
Car car = Mock<Car>();
```

I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Moc.Mock' to 'Car'.

It seems I could do this if I had:

```
Car car = Mock<ICar>();
```

However I don't actually have a `ICar`

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the mock of `Car`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var mockCar = Mock<Car>();
// Configure the mock properties and methods.

Car car = mockCar.Object;
```